# Transfer object via WatchConnectivity from iOS to watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, eventkit, watchconnectivity

I am trying to transfer EventKit Data like `EKCalendars` / `EKEvents` / `EKReminder` from iOS to watchOS via `WatchConnectivity`.

The connection works but I cannot push these objects directly in response. I also cannot use `NSKeyedArchiver` since EKCalendars (example) are not able to get converted to Data.

So, any Idea how I can transfer simple EventKit Data from iOS to watchOS?

An additional hint: I am already fetching these data within watchOS (so no solution) but if the device has an MDM profile it cannot fetch anything but the holiday calendar so I just wanted to test if the iPhone can fetch more (since the MDM profile is stored on iPhone, not on watch) but I can't transfer these data trough WatchConnectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize objects to String, transmit, and deserialize back to the object you need. Probably not the best way, but worked for me.

Comment: Thats right but not EventKit Data.